# jQuery accordion plugin (like Facebook or Google)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, code-reuse

I have seen many scripts for accordion on the internet, but haven't found anything which meets my needs. I want to make a plugin for accordion just like that which Facebook uses. It should work like this:

1. Click to open and close.
2. Add style class while open.
3. Close upon an outside click. **It should not close when click event is inside the accordion box.**

Is there any way to achieve this? Please help if you know. I am new to jQuery...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try Google for 'jQuery' and 'accordion', that should return hundreds of examples to get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a plug-in when 15 lines of code will solve it: it's about changing the order of the click events that trigger on a specific DOM element and on the window using setTimeout.

```
var ShowingAccordion = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
    
       $('.MyAccordionOpener').click(function () {
    
             if ($(this).next('.MyAccordion').is(':visible') === false) {

                 ShowingAccordion = false;
                 $('.MyAccordion').hide(500);
                 $(this).next('.MyAccordion').addClass('SomeClass');
                 $(this).next('.MyAccordion').show(500);
                 setTimeout(function () { ShowingAccordion = true; }, 1);
             }
       });
    
       $('.MyAccordion').click(function () {
        
             ShowingAccordion = false;
             //this is the line that solves your problem
             setTimeout(function () { ShowingAccordion = true; }, 1);
       });
        
    
       $(document).click(function () { 
   
           if (ShowingAccordion === true) {     

               $('.MyAccordion').hide(500);
               ShowingAccordion = false;
           }    
       });
});
```

**And here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RyNgq/26/)**

If it does what you need then you can accept the answer and happy coding!

Comment: Actually, I've got a lots of drop-downs in my website and i think it is not good idea to write a separate script for each drop-down so i need to make a plugin. i just seen the twitter bootstrap script for this but it is not working the way i want and it is kinda hard for me to edit it according to the needs..

Comment: Well then you can adapt it by working with classes! A plug-in is just the same: code that works. Either you're going to be copying-pasting code that you won't understand and that'll be hard to modify for your specific needs (ie. your current situation) or you build your own. I made the changes  to get it working with class; see the edit and the sample jfiddle.

Comment: Note, in case you'd want to use jquery all the way to replace the setTimeout line, the jquery function you're looking for is .proxy(). But try to understand what the 15 lines of code do and you'll be fine.